# Most efficient code to add a dollar sign behind a negative/positive number in JS

Tags: javascript

I have two prices, `A` and `B`, and I want to show `A - B` with a dollar sign.

###### Example:

```
A: 10, B: 30 => -$20
A: 40, B: 5  => $35
```

It is possible to use this function:

```js
function minus(A, B) {
    return `${A-B < 0 && "-"}$${Math.abs(A-B)}`
}
```

I'am just wondering if it's the most efficient way (in terms of speed & performance) to do this, or there's a *wiser* (!) (and maybe faster) approach.

Comment: Performance is irrelevant here.  It's not going to matter.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat

Comment: Optimisation at this level is not really worth it. First focus on the big parts. Shaving of 5ms isnt going to be noticable by anyone

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: @Martijn `Intl.NumberFormat` is Interesting. Never heard of it before.

Comment: This is already the most efficient code. It runs at O(1). You can’t get more efficient than that.

Comment: @SebastianSimon What's O(1)?

Comment: [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/487258)

Comment: @Shahriar Constant time. It doesn’t depend on input size. That’s what _efficiency_ is measured in and where it differs from _speed_.

Answer (score 0):

I didnt check if it is faster, but i prefer this approach:

```
(a, b) => String(a - b).replace(/^-?/, '$&\$')
```

just a matter of taste :)